# "site" is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have this directory structure:

```
my_project/
    site/
        __init__.py
        app.py
    main.py
```

main.py contains this:

```
import site.app
print('Success')
```

Get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import site.app
ImportError: No module named 'site.app'; 'site' is not a package
```

Renaming "site" to any other name, this works correctly.  Example:

```
$ mv site/ foo/
$ echo -e "import foo.app\nprint('Success')" > main.py
$ python main.py
Success
$
```

Is "site" a special package name? Why? How do I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site` is a [standard library module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).  The way to get around it is don't name your package that, just like you wouldn't name it `math` or `sys` or `itertools`.  If you want `my_project` to be a package, make it a package, make it a package by giving it an `__init__.py`.  You don't want to create a top-level package called `site`.

Comment: Ah, of course, how silly. But what if I wanted to name it that anyway?

Comment: @William: You could possibly get around it by changing the order of paths in your `sys.path`.  However, you really shouldn't.  No one else will be able to use your module without doing whatever hacks you did to make it work.

Comment: Is there no way in Python 3 I can specify a "relative import" and say `from . import site.app` or something? (I tried that exact syntax as suggested by [pep 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) ). Let's be clear that I'm not asking about "best practice" but "what's possible". I know it's not the right thing to do :)

Comment: @William: Yes, but to do that you need to make `my_project` a package, as I suggested in my answer.